# How to pick consecutive numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

Ive got a list which actually hold indices for another list. Hence I want to pick out the consecutive numbers from this list

```
index_list=[3,4,8,9,35,36,37]
```

from which i want the output as

```
[3:4], [8:9], [35:37]
```

---------------------MOTIVE:---------------------

I have another master list of words, which has 80 words.

```
  master_list=['was,'it','to,'go,'I'.........]
```

Thus the consecutive indices will help me pick out the required words from master_list as

```
master_list[3:4], master_list[8:9], master_list[35:37]
```

Comment: What should be the fomat of expected output?

Comment: @taurus05  [3:4, 8:9, 35:37] will do

Comment: why did you skip 36?Please be more specific.

Comment: These numbers are _consecutive_, not [concurrent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/concurrent). Also, what's wrong with `[3:37]` as output? How do you decide when to start a new "slice"?

Comment: @ForceBru new slice comes when there a break in constructiveness

Comment: @taurus05 I didnt skip 36, I wrote [35:37], which  means 35,36,37

Comment: @vinita do you expect a 2D list of starting and ending indices of consecutive elements as output? Ex:- `[[3:4],[8:9],[35:37]]` ?

Comment: @taurus05 yes that will do

Comment: @vinita, what output do you expect for input list `[1,3,5,7,9]`? Should it be `[[1, 1], [3, 3], [5, 5], [7, 7], [9, 9]]`

Answer (score 1):

There are likely lots of ways to do this.  Here's one based on `reduce()` and `islice()`:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import islice

qw = [3, 4, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14]

master_list = ['Thus', 'the', 'consecutive', 'indices', 'will', 'help', 'me', 'pick', 'out', 'the', 'required', 'words', 'from', 'master_list', 'as']

def divide(value, element):
    if not value[-1] or element - value[-1][-1] == 1:
        value[-1].append(element)
    else:
        value.append([element])

    return value

slices = [(array[0], array[-1]) for array in reduce(divide, qw, [[]])]

print(slices)

for sliced in slices:
    print(list(islice(master_list, *sliced)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[(3, 4), (8, 9), (12, 14)]
['indices']
['out']
['from', 'master_list']
%
```

Note that this treats the second number in the slice in the customary Python manner in that it's one beyond what we want.  If it's really the last item of what you want then modify this element with a `+ 1`:

```
(array[0], array[-1] + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I have a list = [3, 4, 5, 16, 17, 31, 32, 33, 34] and want indices of consecutive numbers as list of list. [[0,1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7,8]] . Could you pls suggest for this case too ?

Comment: @vinita, this falls out for free as it's what `reduce(divide, qw, [[]])` returns: `[[3, 4, 5], [16, 17], [31, 32, 33, 34]]` before the list comprehension cleans it up for `islice()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using much generalized way:

```
i = 0
final_list = []
flag = True
while flag:
    temp_list = [index_list[i]]
    while (i < len(index_list)-1) and (index_list[i+1] - index_list[i]==1):
        i+=1

    temp_list.append(index_list[i])
    final_list.append(temp_list)
    i+=1
    if i >= len(index_list):
        flag=False

print(final_list)

input : [3,4,8,9,35,36,37]
ouptut : [[3, 4], [8, 9], [35, 37]]

input : [1,3,5,7,9]
output : [[1, 1], [3, 3], [5, 5], [7, 7], [9, 9]]
```

Update:

```
new_list = []
for i, j in final_list:
    new_list.append(list(range(i,j+1)))
print(new_list)

input:  [3, 4, 5, 16, 17, 31, 32, 33, 34] 
output : [[3, 4, 5], [16, 17], [31, 32, 33, 34]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I have a list = [3, 4, 5, 16, 17, 31, 32, 33, 34] and want indices of consecutive numbers as list of list. [[0,1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7,8]] . Could you pls suggest for this case too ?

Comment: This is easy! I've made necessary changes @vinita.